# Fullcalendar hierarchical resource grouping

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to show a vertical resource view in Fullcalendar with resource groupings?

Event data:

```js
resources: [
    {
      id: 'r1',
      title: 'Room A'
    },
    {
      id: 'r2',
      title: 'Room B'
    },
    {
      id: 'd1',
      title: 'Doctor 1'
    },
    {
      id: 'd2',
      title: 'Doctor 2'
    }
  ],
  events: [
    {
      id: '1',
      resourceIds: ['r1', 'd1'],
      title: 'Exam',
      start: '2022-02-14'
    }
  ]
```

Desired view:
[image: Desired Vertical View]

The timeline view seems to do it, but I would like a vertical orientation instead of horizontal.

I found that the [Kendo UI Calendar](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources-grouping-hierarchical)  does it; they call it *Hierarchical Grouping* with *Horizontal Group Orientation*, but I'd like to stick with Fullcalendar if possible.

Comment: Not at the moment no, you'd have to submit a feature request

Comment: I think this feature request is for the same thing. Requested back in 2016 :/ https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4859

Comment: Well they did say, the more people who request it, the more likely they'll do it. It wasn't so popular yet, I guess. Lend your vote.